# What type of trim to use around garage door

Tags: garage

[image]Could anyone tell me what type of material I should buy to trim around a garage door and a window that has no trim. Attached picture is what I'm trying to achieve. It would be for appearance purposes only. My house was built in the late 40s with smooth cement like stucco exterior. Also, what would be the best way to attach it? I would be buying the material from Home Depot.

Comment: **More stucco** and contrasting paint...best bet for lasting as long as the house finish has.

Answer (score 1):

Really anything that you think looks good.  I'm a big fan of plastic, so tired of rotted out wood trim.

Comment: Yes, PVC "boards" can be worked with standard saws, drills, etc. and painted if you want.  As for attaching, take a look at the stucco anchors.  There are kits including a drill bit - I would choose one with longer washer-head anchors, then drill a flat-bottom larger hole partway through your PVC trim and put the washer head anchor through the bottom of that, covering it up afterwards with a PVC plug.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you both.